# Comparing Reactive Forms to filter out only updated values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a formGroup with the following structure:

mainFormGroup: {
    firstControl: '',
    secondControl: '',
    innerFormGroup: {
        firstInnerControl: '',
        secondInnerControl: ''
    }
}

After making changes, I can seek the values from "mainFromGroup.value". But it will give me the values for all the controls/subgroups.
Rather, I only want those fields whose values have been altered by the user. Suppose user changes only "firstInnerControl" then I should have something just like the following:

mainFormGroup: {
    innerFormGroup: {
        firstInnerControl: "New Value"
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a listener for changes, and subscribe to it.  Here is a link to angular documentation: [Angular Reactive Forms Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Basically you would subscribe to the changes in your component, on Init:

```
this.myForm.controls['name'].valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  console.log("Name changed: ", data);

})
```

Comment: But this would defeat the purpose. For instance , name is changed to "ABC" and then back to "". It would emit the stream of events which I do not want, since the end value is same.

Comment: @RachitLosalka I don't understand.  You specifically asked how you can listen for changes to an individual control and not the whole form.  What exactly do you want?  You probably need to handle making the decision as to whether the value change is significant or not.